# Spring 3.1 autowiring generic class with multiple generics parameters

Tags: java, spring, generics

I am trying to implement a generic DAO, but i got one problem...

Here my problem :

```
public class ClassA<T,P,S> extends JpaRepository<T, Integer>{
   dostuff<P,S>(){...}
}

@Autowired
private ClassA<BeanA,BeanB,BeanC> classA;
```

At that point, I get this error when compiling :

```
Error creating bean with name 'ClassA': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: interface java.lang.Object
```

According to what I have already seen in this site, Spring 4.0 should do the stuff, but I am working with Spring 3.1 and upgrading is not possible...

Maybe my tests could help you to answer my question :

```
public class ClassA extends JpaRepository<BeanA, Integer>{
   dostuff<BeanB,BeanC>(){...}
}

@Autowired
private ClassA classA;
```

and

```
public class ClassA<T extends BeanA,P extends BeanB, S extends BeanC> extends JpaRepository<T, Integer>{
   dostuff<P,S>(){...}
}

@Autowired
private ClassA<BeanA,BeanB,BeanC> classA;
```

work perfectly fine.

Thanks in advance for your advices ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to autowire by specifying qualifier explicitly for the specified repository, for example

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("classA")
private ClassA<BeanA,BeanB,BeanC> classA;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is not working, error now said that there is no bean candidate to this qualifier

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Service(value="first")
public class ClassA extends JpaRepository<BeanA, Integer>{
   dostuff<BeanB,BeanC>(){...}
}

@Autowired
@Qualifier("first")
private ClassA classA;
```

and

```
@Service(value="second")
public class ClassA<T extends BeanA,P extends BeanB, S extends BeanC> extends JpaRepository<T, Integer>{
   dostuff<P,S>(){...}
}

@Autowired
@Qualifier("second")
private ClassA<BeanA,BeanB,BeanC> classA;
```

Without *@Qualifier* it's possible only in Spring 4.

Comment: Man that is exactly what i wrote at the end of my question... ( without service and qualifier, which is still working)

The point is that i want to declare multiple ClassA without duplicating the code : 

private ClassA<BeanA,BeanB,BeanC> classA;

private ClassA<BeanAbis,BeanBbis,BeanCbis> classAbis;